# Which environment should I use to align my equations to the left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, best-practices

I would like to know the "best" environment to align equations to the left. I already use `fleqn` at the beginning of my document and `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$` when I write equations in the "enumerate" environment. I would like to align my text like this,

[image]

but I don't know what is the best environment to do that and how to do it. Also, sometimes, I get weird indentations, at the beginning of lines depending on the environment and I sometimes have my text left aligned while right aligned (see third block of equation) and I was wondering why Latex aligns my equations like this.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        I=O+P \\
        \int^o_p (x-1)^2 \,dx
    \end{align*}

$\begin{aligned}
    I=O+P \\
    \int^o_p (x-1)^2 \,dx
\end{aligned}$


\begin{align*}
    u_1\in U_1 \Rightarrow u_1\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    u_2\in U_2 \Rightarrow u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \textrm{Since } U_1 \cup U_2 \textrm{ is a subspace of $V$, } u_1+u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \Rightarrow u_1+u_2\in U_1 \textrm{ or } u_1+u_2\in U_2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    R_{eq}=\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1} &= \left(\frac{1}{3000}+\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{-1} \\
    &= 750
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you (a) replace the first two `align*` environments with `gather*` environments and (b) start using alignment points in the `aligned` environment (and place a `\noindent` directive before the `aligned` environment).

As an alternative to suggestion (a) above, consider (a') keep using the `align*` environments but start using alignment markers (`&`), one at the start of both lines in the first `align*` environment, and one at the start of all four lines in the second `align*` environment.

You also asked,

> sometimes, I get weird indentations, at the beginning of lines depending on the environment and I sometimes have my text left aligned while right aligned (see third block of equation) and I was wondering why Latex aligns my equations like this.

That would be because you're not using a single alignment marker in that `align*` environment. See suggestion (a') above.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <-- that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
     I=O+P \\
     \int^0_p (x-1)^2 \,dx
\end{gather*}

\noindent % <-- important
$\begin{aligned}
    &I=O+P \\
    &{\int^0_p (x-1)^2 \,dx}
\end{aligned}$

\begin{gather*}
    u_1\in U_1 \Rightarrow u_1\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    u_2\in U_2 \Rightarrow u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \textrm{Since } U_1 \cup U_2 \textrm{ is a subspace of $V$, } u_1+u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \Rightarrow u_1+u_2\in U_1 \textrm{ or } u_1+u_2\in U_2
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
    R_{\mathrm{eq}}=\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1} 
         &= \left(\frac{1}{3000}+\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{-1} \\
         &= 750
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Mico has suggested better markup, so here I concentrate on explaining the output that you get. Mainly it is (almost always) user error to use `align` with no alignment points.

I annotated your original example

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}

Math block left alighted (fleqn, and mathindent is 0), math within the block fush right (as no \&.)
    \begin{align*}
        I=O+P \\
        \int^o_p (x-1)^2 \,dx
    \end{align*}

Math block indented by paragraph indent as inline. Each line of math within the block flush right as no \&

$\begin{aligned}
    I=O+P \\
    \int^o_p (x-1)^2 \,dx
\end{aligned}$


As case 1, math block flush left but each line is flush right within the block.
\begin{align*}
    u_1\in U_1 \Rightarrow u_1\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    u_2\in U_2 \Rightarrow u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \textrm{Since } U_1 \cup U_2 \textrm{ is a subspace of $V$, } u_1+u_2\in U_1 \cup U_2 \\
    \Rightarrow u_1+u_2\in U_1 \textrm{ or } u_1+u_2\in U_2
\end{align*}

Math block flush left , aligned on =
\begin{align*}
    R_{eq}=\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1} &= \left(\frac{1}{3000}+\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{-1} \\
    &= 750
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```